# frameless UWP dock

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp-appwindow

I'm looking to make dock/utility which appears around the mouse cursor, and I'm wondering if someone can point me in the right/optimal direction of making it.

my initial idea was to make a second window (main window is planned to be the settings panel) but I can't seem to find any way to hide the default windows frame so I can design it from scratch. my end goal is to make a circle or square which can be showed/hidden on a hot key, and that will be rendered over all other applications when active, or auto hidden when not in use, aka not the active "window".

any help or pointer to docs to read would be much appreciated.